# bsddb.db.DBPermissionsError (1 'operation not permitted') - Python 2.7

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, shelve

I was trying to save my data permanently and I encountered this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\new  1. - C¾pia.py", line 6, in <module>
    database = shelve.open('sub.db', 'c')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shelve.py", line 239, in open
    return DbfilenameShelf(filename, flag, protocol, writeback)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shelve.py", line 223, in __init__
    Shelf.__init__(self, anydbm.open(filename, flag), protocol, writeback)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\anydbm.py", line 85, in open
    return mod.open(file, flag, mode)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\dbhash.py", line 18, in open
    return bsddb.hashopen(file, flag, mode)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\bsddb\__init__.py", line 364, in hashopen
    d.open(file, db.DB_HASH, flags, mode)
bsddb.db.DBPermissionsError: (1, 'Operation not permitted')
```

I have tried to change to anydbm and the error stays the same.
I have tested with a code simple as that:

```
import shelve

database = shelve.open('sub.db', 'c')
database.close()
```

I already searched the Internet to find an answer and didn't find anything to help me.

Thanks in advance,

João Pinhal

***Edit:***
It was the permissions in the directory.
I couldn't create the file in the Desktop.

Comment: Either you don't have permission to edit that file, or you don't have permission to create a new file in the current directory.  Does `sub.db` exist already, or are you trying to create it?

Comment: Yeah I think it is the permissions in the directory. Thank You